# Microsoft ADAL authentication on Android

Tags: android, azure, adal, android-syncadapter

I'm trying to create a `SyncAdapter` for Microsoft calendars and the first step is `Authentication`. i'm using `com.microsoft.aad:adal:2.0.4-alpha`and using this code for first authentication:

```
getAuthenticationContext().acquireToken(
                mContextActivity,
                Constants.SCOPES.split(" "),
                null,
                Constants.CLIENT_ID,
                Constants.REDIRECT_URI,
                PromptBehavior.Auto,
                new AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final AuthenticationResult authenticationResult) {
                        if (authenticationResult != null && authenticationResult.getStatus() ==
                                        AuthenticationResult.AuthenticationStatus.Succeeded) {
                            dependencyResolver = new ADALDependencyResolver(
                                    getAuthenticationContext(),
                                    resourceId,
                                    Constants.CLIENT_ID);
                            token = authenticationResult.getToken();
                            UserInfo userInfo = authenticationResult.getUserInfo();
                            if (userInfo != null) {
                                userIdentifier = new UserIdentifier(userInfo.getUniqueId(),
                                                            UserIdentifier.UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception t) {
                        Log.e("initialize", "onError : " + t.getMessage());
                        result.setException(t);
                    }
                }
            );
```

this works perfectly and after entering username and password i can get token.

**BUT** this is for `sync adapter` and at some point i need to get token silently. so i used this code:

```
public void getTokenSilent() {

    getAuthenticationContext()
            .acquireTokenSilent(Constants.SCOPES.split(" "),
                                Constants.CLIENT_ID,
                                userIdentifier,
                                new AuthenticationCallback<AuthenticationResult>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(
                                            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult) {
                                        UserInfo userInfo = authenticationResult.getUserInfo();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Exception e) {
                                        Log.e("getTokenSilent", "onError : " + e.getMessage());
                                    }
                                });
}
```

After executing this code i got the error:

```
AUTH_REFRESH_FAILED_PROMPT_NOT_ALLOWED Prompt is not allowed and failed to get token: ver:2.0.4-alpha
onError : Refresh token is failed and prompt is not allowed
```

how can i resolve this error and get or refresh token silently?

tnx in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the token silently, there are two ways for using Azure AD V2.0 endpoint.

First, acquire the access token and refresh token interactively, then get the access token in the cache or renew the access token using refresh token via `acquireTokenSilent` method.

Second is that the Azure AD V2.0 endpoint also support the **Client Credentials flow**(refer [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/auth_overview#deciding-between-the-azure-ad-and-azure-ad-v20-endpoints)) which normally used for the service daemon application. However the MSAL for android doesn't support this flow at present. You need to implement it yourself. You can follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds) about detail of this flow. And this flow only works for the Azure AD account.

Comment: In first part of my code i get the token interactively, The refresh token has private access and i can not see it. what do you mean by "get the access token in the cache" ?

Comment: Fei, he is using ADAL experimental, not MSAL.  @mehdok I highly recommend moving to [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android) if you intend on using the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint.  If you are happy to use v1, change your library version to 1.12.  The version you're currently using is not encouraged and is in Alpha.

Comment: @DanielDobalian, tnx for you answer, i don't have any insist to use version 2, BUT i can not find out how to register my app with version 1.
do you have any clue?
tnx in advance.

Comment: @mehdok Do you have the Azure AD tenant? If yes, you can login portal of Azure and register the app. Refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-app-registration) to register the app for the Azure AD.

Comment: sure i have, tnx for your replay, i will test it.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT, hi, finally i got some time to test your idea, i registred an `active directory app` with api version 1, and followed the sample code from here: [link](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/Docs/Android) to authenticate and get token. it show me user password box and after i enter the user name it show a progress and again it show user pass box, no matter how many time i enter my user name, it keep showing me the boxes, do you have any idea? tnx in advance